# Cardinality of the set $\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {{a_i}\over {5^i}}\} \subset \mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Cardinality  of the set $$A=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {{a_i}\over {5^i}}:a_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}\right\} \subset \mathbb R$$

$A.$ Finite

$B.$ countably infinite.

$C.$ uncountable but does not contain an open interval.

$D.$ contains an open interval.

Now I guess  the  set  would  be  uncountable because  cardinality of each sequence ${\{{a_n\over 5^n}\}}_n$  is  **countably infinite product of a finite set , namely $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.** So  option  $C$  or  $D$  will  be  the  case .  But  what  about  the  open  interval  thing $?$  How  to  find  that  out  $?$

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: Hint: Base $5$ representation. $A=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

A is actually the same as $\{x: x=0.a_1a_2a_3...,a_i=0,1,2,3,4\}$. Compare this with 10-based number system we all are familiar with, which is $\{x: x=0.a_1a_2a_3...,a_i=0,1,2,3,...,9\}$. The two are actually equivalent, in that any number in the first set can be uniquely identified in the second set, and vice versa.

Comment: So , $A$ is  the set $(0,1)$  of  real  numbers  right $?$ . So it  does  contain  an  open  interval .

Comment: @user118494 I think you should be able to take it from there, no?

Comment: @user118494 No, it should be $[0,1]$. $0.000...=0$ and $0.444...=1$. I think you know $0.999...=1$ in 10-based number system.

Comment: @Hua : Yes , yes. So it's $D$, no $?$

Comment: @user118494 Yes, actually it is uncountable and contains an open interval.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Think of the development of a real number in base $5$: any real number $x\ge 0$ has a development:
$$x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{a_i}{5^i},\quad a_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$$
and this development is unique is unique if the sequence $(a_i)$ is not eventually $(4,4,4,\dots)$.

So the set $A$ is but the set of real non negative numbers with a $0$ integer part.

Comment: Sorry  but I  do  not  think  I  understand . Would  you  please  elaborate  $?$

Comment: Ok. So  it  is  option  $D.$